Adding additional keys to an environment and maintaining existing keys
Using the solution suggested in Wrapping the Tasks Command in a New Environment
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\itemJ}{m O{}}{%
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \task #1 \\ \textit{Solution:} ~ #2 }
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{harrytasks}
  {
    O{} % optional options
    D(){1} % number of columns
  }
  {
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
  }
  {
    \harry_task_make:nnV {#1} {#2} \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \harry_task_make:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \begin{tasks}[#1](#2) #3 \end{tasks}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \harry_task_make:nnn {nnV}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\title{Tasks Package Example with \texttt{NewDocumentCommand}}
\author{Your Name}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section*{Example Task Lists}

\begin{harrytasks}
  \itemJ{First item}[This is the solution]
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
\end{harrytasks}

\medskip

%Ideal solution:
\begin{harrytasks}[label=\alph*., label-format={\bfseries}, cols = 2]
  \itemJ{First item}
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
  \itemJ{Fourth item}
\end{harrytasks}

\end{document}

I am trying (and have been unsuccessful at doing so) to move the column function to a new key called 'cols', whilst maintaining the ability to add other keys, e.g. label=\alph*., label-format={\bfseries}.
Is it possible to refactor this code to enable additional keys on top of the optional options?

you can set it up to process key-values for the first argument and pass any unrecognised ones through to tasks. \keys_define:nn { harry } { cols .int_set:N = \l_harry_cols_int, cols .initial:n = 1} and then use \keys_set_known:nnN { harry } { #1 } \l_tmpa_tl and pass the token list to tasks. is that what you mean?

Thanks that worked, will add it in as a solution

Solution using @cfr's comment:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { harry }
  {
    cols .int_set:N = \l_harry_cols_int,
    cols .initial:n = 1
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\itemJ}{m O{}}{%
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \task #1 \\ \textit{Solution:} ~ #2 }
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{harrytasks}
  {
    O{} % optional options
  }
  {
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpb_tl
    \keys_set_known:nnN { harry } { #1 } \l_tmpb_tl
  }
  {
    \harry_task_make:VV \l_tmpb_tl \l_tmpa_tl
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \harry_task_make:nn #1#2
  {
    \begin{tasks}[#1](\int_use:N \l_harry_cols_int) #2 \end{tasks}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \harry_task_make:nn {VV}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\title{Tasks Package Example with \texttt{NewDocumentCommand}}
\author{Your Name}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section*{Example Task Lists}

\begin{harrytasks}[cols=1]
  \itemJ{First item}[This is the solution]
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
\end{harrytasks}

\medskip

\begin{harrytasks}[cols=2, label=\alph*., label-format={\bfseries}]
  \itemJ{First item}
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
  \itemJ{Fourth item}
\end{harrytasks}

\end{document}

